# Windows Update w/machines not on network

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-update

We have a scenario where we have 60 computers that need to be loaded with Windows7 at our company as well as have all windows updates installed.  Our company has an internet especially for visitors and since these computers are for a client the contract states they are never to be connected to our own companys network.  Therefore, they must be installed on the visitor side of our network.  The problem is we will have to install our own hubs (can't use switches as they would take the other switches down) to install the updates onto multiple computers at once.  If we do this it would take around 3 hours per install.  Does anyone know a way to download all the necessary updates from windows and put them on a disk or flash drive?  This way we can easily load teh updates? The other option is to update one system and make a copy of it and run sysprep to install this copy on all the other machines.  We have yet to receive word if the contract will allow us to do this.

To point one other thing out, the contract stipulates the machines always receive the latest updates but will never be able to access the internet upon shipping and arrival to their destination.  So we are unsure how we will get these updates to these machines as well.  Any Ideas?

Comment: Given than I've never seen a 100mb hub (although technically they could exist) and any 10mb hub is going to be 15+ years old now, I find myself wondering exactly how you're going to achieve that part of the contract...

Comment: How, exactly, would any new switches "take the other switches down"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your contract is going to have to include a WSUS server to go with the client computers. The WSUS server will need access to the internet in order to download Windows updates. The client computers can then be configured to download and install updates via the WSUS server.

See here for genberal WSUS information:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb332157.aspx

And here for configuring non-AD clients:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd939844(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: +1, WSUS is the best option, if there isn't any internet you can't use Windows InTune but that may be good for ensuring updates in the future as well as maintenance. Although you might be able to team up NAP with WSUS for update remediation on the visitor network. Weird requirements though.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong with Sysprep.
In fact it's the quickest method for imaging 60 identical machines, without waiting hours for updates to install (WSUS server or not).

Don't read too far into the contract. Meet your deliverables, and wash your hands of it.

Comment: bbezaire: the question states "To point one other thing out, the contract stipulates the machines always receive the latest updates but will never be able to access the internet upon shipping and arrival to their destination". I took that to mean that the OP will be responsible for updating the machines after they've been delivered.

Answer (score 0):

I second the recommendation of setting up a WSUS. However, if for some reason that is not an option for you (due to network restrictions or something), you could try [WSUS Offline Update](http://www.wsusoffline.net/) instead.